# Strange issue happening on a few 5.0 and 5.1 devices

Tags: android, crash

In my app, I'm facing a weird issue I can't explain. I can't even give you a logcat or something as I don't know where it is actually coming from, I can only describe the error:

My app Daily works well on some 5.0 and 5.1 devices, the HTC One Max for example. It does NOT work for Samsung and Sony devices running 5.1 and 5.0, maybe also at a 6.0 Samsung. The app just stays white for a few seconds and nothing happens then.

If you have any further questions about the app itself, you can just ask.

The app is using a MultiDexApplication and MultiDex itself if this might help.

Thanks.

Comment: Check your targetSdk. It must be set to 23 to run on a Android 6.0 device

Comment: My targetSdk is set right, it has absolutely nothing to do with this.